# Append in existing div class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I append in existing div class 3 below ?

Example:

```
<div id="A" class="1">
   <div class="2">
      <div class="3">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want to append?

Comment: if you're using jquery: $('.3').append('Hello!'); (see here http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: BTW: i don't recommend a number as css class name

Comment: It's not a number, it was just an example.

Comment: Anyway, it works.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Since you say the jQuery solution works, I added the jQuery tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.3').append('your text/element here');
```

Comment: I guess you wrote too fast: it should be `$('.3').append()` I'd say, just as JeanLuc wrote in his comment.